# Is CAValueFunction only usable for properties of CATransform3D type?

Tags: core-animation

All the value functions provided by Core Animation map scale values to `CATransform3D` values and it doesn't offer any way to create `CAValueFunction` instances other than `+functionWithName:`.

So it seems `CAPropertyAnimation.valueFunction` is only usable for properties of CATransform3D type. Do I get it right?